# Metadata and normalization

Tags: database, dataset, ssms, metadata

I'm a beginner with SQL. I want to do some data exploration in SSMS for my portfolio. I decided to use a [database](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lasaljaywardena/global-cryptocurrency-price-database?resource=download) from Kaggle for it. The database contains a .csv file called metadata:

[image]

There's also a folder for data with files from paths in metadata. So, my question is how should I import metadata and data in SSMS and should this metadata be a part of normalization?

I tried to google it but couldn't find a clear explanation.

Comment: You do not need that metadata as far as I can see. Concentrate on the currency data.